# python equivalent for char datatype in C

Tags: python

is there any python datatype equivalent to char datatype in C?
in C, a char variable can store only 1 byte of information. for eg the C code and its output

```
void main()
{
   char a;
   printf("Enter the value");
   scanf("%d",&a);
   printf("A = %d",a);
}
```

output

```
Enter the value 255
A = 255

Enter the value 256
A = 0
```

I want the exact output in python. please help me. thanks in advance.

Comment: What's wrong with `a%256` for your usecase?

Comment: No, python doesn't have such a small integer type. In fact, practically speaking, it's integer types can be arbitrarily large and will never roll over (specifically, a `long` type is arbitrarily large, but there appears to be automatic promotion from `int` to `long` when needed). See this doc for details: http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-long-complex

Answer (score 3):

Given your usecase is that you want modular behaviour, just take your input as an int, and do `a%256` to find the result you want.

Answer (score 2):

Marcin's answer is probably want you wanted based on your question, and vorac's answer has another way, but since I started to type this:  Note that python does have a struct library that would also allow you to manipulate things as bytes, shorts, etc.

Example:

```
import struct
import socket
s = socket.socket()
s.connect("127.0.0.1",5000)  # connect to some TCP based network (and ignore any sort of endiness issues, which could be solved with other arguments to struct.pack)
data1 = 100
data2 = 200
data_packed = struct.pack("cc",chr(data1),chr(data2)) # pack 2 numbers as bytes (chars)
s.send(data_packed) # put it on the network as raw bytes
data_packed_out = s.recv(100) # get raw bytes from the network
data3,data4 = struct.unpack("cc",data_packed_out) # unpack said bytes
```

Comment: +1 This is correct and useful. Note, though, that once you extract to python variables, you will have int objects, not magical bytes.

Comment: Agreed; also meant to add that if you are starting with integers and trying to pack, you probably want to do chr(dataX % 256) to avoid a range exception

Answer (score 0):

[ctypes](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html) is a library for python to work with ... c-types. Useful when communicating with devices that speak c.